# Optimization of for-loop (vlookup + copy-paste from one worksheet to another)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, vlookup, copy-paste, xlwings

first time poster here and quite new to coding whatsoever. Big fan of this community - you helped me a lot during my start. Appreciate all the guidance and criticism of my code you guys can provide

I'm trying to replace my nested for loop with something else to speed my code performance. Currently it is way to slow for range(1, 50) - the end range can go as high as 90 (number of projects in xlsx). I was thinking about map() function, but to be honest, i'm clueless on how to convert my loops into it.

Using xlwings to update excel as is. Got a report spreadsheet and a status spreadsheet, they are uneven in length. Trying to match corresponding row of project number in both report and status spreadsheet (sort of a vlookup). If they match, take values from columns(2,3 and 4) of report file and copy them to columns (2,14 and 16) of status file.

I tried searching and applying some optimization techniques - removed unnecessary variables assignments and data type changes - but having little to none coding experience, i failed to understand how for example map() can be applied here. I'm sure tho, there is some way i can run this script faster on low end computer as well.

Time taken in the loop

- Range of 30(outer), 68(inner):  42.19
- Range of 40(outer), 20(inner):  10.53
- Range of 70(outer), 68(inner):  90.93

EDIT:
I'm using xlwings exclusively for the cell updates, because I need to keep the formatting of the original file, macros, formulas, etc. Whenever possible, I'm creating separate excel to do some computing (using pandas for example), but at the end, i always need to put the output in the 'status' excel. So here you see separate excel where i used pandas to filter, re-order, remove columns etc - 'report' and then comparing it to 'status' sheet (original file), finding matches and copying columns.

Sample block of code

```
report = wb_report.sheets['Sheet1']
status = wb.sheets['GEO']

for row in range(2, status_lwr_cell):        # go from row 2 until last filled cell of status file
    for r_row in range(2, report_lwr_cell):  # go from row 2 until last filled cell of report file
        
        # check if project nbr in status is corresponding to project nbr in report
        if status.range(row, 1).value == report.range(r_row, 1).value:
            report.range(r_row, 2).value = status.range(row, 2).value
            report.range(r_row, 4).value = status.range(row, 14).value
            report.range(r_row, 3).value = status.range(row, 16).value
            break  # skip rest of the inner loop and go for another check
```

Comment: Try to do what you can with arrays, i.e. read in a nested list of both sheets, then do the comparison in Python between the lists and in the end, put together a nested list that you assign to a top-left cell and write out everything in one go. You want to have as few `.value` calls as possible.

Comment: Thanks Felix, I went from for loop to just preparing all the data in separate sheet via pandas and copying just entire columns into my spreadsheet (3 of them, about 70 cells long). It's taking 22.51s to update it, so i take it as a success getting down from 90s.